# Undo on secondary NSWindow, Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa

I'm attempting to implement a properties panel as a secondary window to a NSDocument based app.  The implementation shows a NSWindow (via a NSWindowController).

The goal is that properties modifier in the secondary window (the "Properties window") should be undo-able using CMD-Z if either of the main (the document) or the secondary (properties window) are active.

For some reason, this is eluding me.

My current implementation / test is very basic.
To test this idea, I have a NSSlider bound to a property called 'aValue', exposed on the "Properties" NWindowController. This does something like this:

```
- (void) undoAValueUsing:(int)oldValue {
   self.aValue = oldValue;
}

- (void)setAValue:(int)aValue {
    if(aValue != _aValue) {
    NSLog(@"Value is now: %d", aValue);
    [[self.undoManager prepareWithInvocationTarget:self] undoAValueUsing:_aValue];
    [self.undoManager setActionName:@"Ra"];
    _aValue = aValue;
}
```

Thus any change to the property records an "undo" action.

The problem is, no undo appears... it's as if it's not registered, or if the active menu item is looking at some other undo manager. CMD-Z just produces a "beep" (aka: noop).

The full code to this simplistic example is here: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/421935/TestApp/Test.zip

The idea is that you click the button to view the properties panel, make changes to the topmost slider (no other slider has undo implemented) and you *should* be able to CMD-Z t undo it.

btw: if you look at the example code you'll see i've tried setting the custom window manager.undoManager to be the document.undoManager. It made no difference.

Hmm. I think I'm going nuts. This *should* be so simple!
Must be missing something obvious!

Any revelations o-people-of-the-internet?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the answer is simple.  Have the document set itself to be the delegate of the NSWindow (the secondary one).  Then implement:

```
  - (NSUndoManager *)windowWillReturnUndoManager:(NSWindow *)window
```

on the Document, returning the Doc's undoManager.

Done.